# Transform an almost positive definite matrix to positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix A (n by n) is constructed as followed.

1. $A(i,i)= -\sum^{k=n}_{k=1}A(i,k), k \neq i. $
2. A is symmetric.
3. All the off-diagonal elements are negative except two elements $A(p,q)$ and $A(q, p)$: $A(i,j)<0$, when $i\neq j, i,j \neq p, i,j \neq q.$

Therefore the matrix is diagonal dominant for all the rows except row $p$.  $A$ is almost a M-matrix. Is there any technique we can transfer this matrix $A$ to a positive definite matrix? Actually transforming part of $A$ to positive definite will be good enough.

Comment: So you have a (symmetric?) matrix which is "almost" positive definite? What do you want to do with it? Do you want to use SPD solvers? If so and you can identify a large SPD submatrix (it seems that you can), you could use Schur complements combined with the Woodbury formula.

Comment: Yes. The matrix is symmetric and I am looking for using SPD solver to solve it. Woodbury formula for matrix inversion? The matrix I have is like thousands by thousands scale. Direct inversion may be costly. Can you explain a little bit more? Thank you! @PavelJiranek